# LR 11. Web-siebel script is failing while running for multiple iterations

Tags: loadrunner, siebel

I have recorded the Siebel CRM using the Loadrunner Siebel web protocol. 
I have used the Siebel correlation library while recording the script. 
The replay is sucessful for a single iterations.

But when we are running for mutiple iterations, the script is only passing the 1st iteration and faling at the subsequent iterations.

My code:

```
    web_submit_data("start.swe_28", 
    "Action=https://IP_siebel/oa/start.swe", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "TargetFrame=", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=", 
    "Snapshot=t30.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=SWER", "Value=0", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWEVI", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWERowId", "Value={Siebel_Star_Array_Op87_rowid}", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWEMethod", "Value=PickRecord", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWEC", "Value={Siebel_SWECount}", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWEReqRowId", "Value=1", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWERPC", "Value=1", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWENeedContext", "Value=false", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWEApplet", "Value=ATC Cash Product Pick Applet", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWEView", "Value=ATC Opty Cash CC View", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWEField", "Value=s_8_1_73_0", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWECmd", "Value=InvokeMethod", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWESP", "Value=false", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWEBID", "Value=-1", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWETS", "Value={SiebelTimeStamp}", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWEDIC", "Value=true", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWEP", "Value=26_ATC Cash Credit Calculator Form Applet9_EditField{Siebel_Star_Array_Op73_rowid_Length}_{Siebel_Star_Array_Op73_rowid}9_s_5_1_7_02_16", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWERowIds", "Value=SWERowId0={Siebel_Star_Array_Op73_rowid}", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);
```

Siebel error (SBL-UIF-00313)

Error text:

> Step2.c(450): Error -26372: ContentCheck Rule
>   "Status_Error1" in Application "Siebel" triggered. Text
>   "`Status`Error`" matched (count=1)    [MsgId: MERR-26372]
>   Step2.c(450): web_submit_data("start.swe_28") highest
>   severity level was "ERROR", 474 body bytes, 259 header bytes      [MsgId:
>   MMSG-26388] Ending action Step2_CreateZajavka.

I think error in *"Name=SWEP", "Value=26_ATC Cash Credit Calculator Form Applet9_EditField{Siebel_Star_Array_Op73_rowid_Length}_{Siebel_Star_Array_Op73_rowid}9_s_5_1_7_02_16", ENDITEM,*

In first iteration *{Siebel_Star_Array_Op73_rowid}* = 3-1FGSAY3
In second iteration *{Siebel_Star_Array_Op73_rowid}* = [ID] = "3-1FGEAY8"

How i can correlate this or cut wrong symbols ([ID] = )?
Please, help me!

Comment: All work after manual correlation for rowid

Answer (score 0):

Then you have some additional dynamic elements to address.

http://www.perfbytes.com/dynamic-data-correlation

Never rely upon automation where you don't have the manual skills to address any gaps that the automation fails to cover.  Or, the short hand, with a silver bullet you still need to know how to aim whether your target is a werewolf or not.